# req.body de form siempre llega vacio (nodeJs)

Tags: nodejs, formularios

Estoy haciendo un proyectito de un ecommerce y al intentar crear un nuevo producto, intentando capturar los datos de los input, siempre llega la info vacía. La consola solo muestra: {} 
Lo miro y miro, cambio cosas pero nada hace que llegue con la info jaja
Les agradecería si pueden ayudarme :) 
Les dejo captura del form, el router y el método (que aún no está creado del todo, es solo para recibir la info) 
Muchas gracias!

[image: Form]

[image: Router]

[image: Metodo]

Comment: Estas usando express? Agregaste express.json() ?

Comment: Sisi, estaba todo puesto!
Sólo tenía que sacar el enctype xq no estaba usando multer aún para poder subir los archivos jaja

Comment: el código va como texto, no como imagen. Si quisiéramos tratar de reproducir el problema tendríamos que transcribir todo, no crees?

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente lo que te falta es esto al principio de tu `app.js` o `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); //Esto es para formData
app.use(express.json())
```